# allow users in table 1 to edit content in table 2 php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a requirement to allow users in 1 table to edit records in a second table where both tables are in a single mysql database. There are exactly the same number of users as records.

For example user in table 1 with id 234 should only be able to edit the record in table 2 with the id 234.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated bearing in mind I am not an expert. I have spent several hours searching for a result before posting but have found nothing I can implement.

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Just make sure the two ID's match in your PHP. **<? if($table_1_id == $table_2_id ) { // They can edit! } else { // Send them away! } ?>**

Answer (score 0):

how about this syntax?

```
UPDATE `table1` as `t1`, `table2` as `t2`
SET `t1`.`attribute1`="foo", `t2`.`attribute2`="bar"
WHERE `t1`.`id`=`t2`.`id` AND `t1`.`id`=234
```

see [the mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: I think he's looking for PHP code to make sure that the user's ID matches the ID in table 2 before the table is updated. I think?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I wasn't expecting anyone to get back so quick... I think my requirement will largely be done with php (I think)... as it stands the website displays 2300 pages of data which I would like individuals to be able to edit, so I'm looking for a 'log in' screen, whereby once the user logs in they are directed to their specific 'form' which they then can edit and save... I know there's a tutorial out there somewhere but it's eluding me so far... but thanks again for the input Jan Turon,

Comment: @user2307736: then Kacey's comment to your question should solve it.

Comment: Thanks Kacey and Jan, I'll take your line Kacey and will probably get there in the end !